# Salvar log na pasta da aplicação

Tags: python

Olá, fiz uma aplicação e adicionei log (logging), porém está salvando na pasta raiz '/', e eu quero que salve no pasta raiz da aplicação MonitoraContrato/, como faço.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename= 'Log.txt', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(funcName)s => %(message)s')
logging.info('INICIO DO PROGRAMA...')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você apenas definiu o arquivo como `Log.txt` ele o salvará o diretório onde você iniciou a aplicação, a forma mais simples de resolver o problema é

````
    from os import path
    # ...
    log_file = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)),"Log.txt")
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file, ...) ```
````

Isto irá pegar o diretório onde do programa para compor o caminho do arquivo de log.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigada!.